# LIst Magento Products in a block and split them into columns

Tags: magento, split, product

I am searching for a way to list magento products from a certain category in a block. I created a phtml for extracting the products:

```
<?php

$categoryid = 4;

$category = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();
$category->load($categoryid);
$collection = $category->getProductCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');


foreach ($collection as $_product) { ?>
<a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl(); ?>"><?php echo $_product->getName(); ?></a><br></li>

<?php } ?>
```

Then I included a block to this phtml file.

How can I split the products into columns with a break?

Like

1 6  11 ...
2 7  12 
3 8  13 
4 9  14 
5 10 15

Any solution would be great! I think this is just PHP.

Thanks a lot!
Hans

Thanks Mahmood Rehman,
I tried this version, but it did also not work:

```
<?php

$categoryid = 4;

$category = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();
$category->load($categoryid);
$collection = $category->getProductCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
?>
<ul>
    <?php $i=0;
    foreach ($collection as $_product) {  ?>

     <?php if ($i++%4 == 0): ?>
            </ul><ul>
            <?php endif ?>
                <li>
                    <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(135); ?>" width="135" height="135" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" /></a>
                    <h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></a></h2>
        <br></li>

    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: By columns you means ?

Comment: Like 6 columns and after 4 items split to other column

<ul>
<li>item1</li>
<li>item2</li>
<li>item3</li>
<li>item4</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li>item5</li>
<li>item6</li>
<li>item7</li>
<li>item8</li>
</ul>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do like this :

```
<ul>
    <?php $i=0;
    foreach ($collection as $_product) {  ?>

     <?php if ($i++%4 == 0): ?>
            </ul><ul>
            <?php endif ?>
                <li>
                    <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(135); ?>" width="135" height="135" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" /></a>
                    <h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></a></h2>
        <br></li>

    <?php $i++;} ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Glad to hear this.If this solved your problem then please accept my answer so anyone can use the code for reference.

Comment: Hi Mahmood, Thanks for posting, but it did not work. As you can see in my comment question above. It breaks the navigation.

Comment: Did you increment the value of `$i` ?.Check my updated answer.

Comment: Mahmood, You are the greatest! Thanks!